# How can I hide the Adobe Reader toolbar when displaying a PDF in Java WebBrowser control?

Tags: java, pdf, plugins

I have seen the same question with .NET and a file, but this is different:

I have a Java aplication that calls a method with some parameters, response between them:

```
myCode.launchPDF(response, someOtherData...)
```

The function *launchPDF* get the *ByteArrayOutputStream* with the parameters and **use the response to show a PDF to the user**:

```
private static void launchPDF(HttpServletResponse response, Object... someData) {
    try{

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = getPDFFromWS(...);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"example.pdf");
        OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();

        if ( baos!=null && out1!=null)
            baos.writeTo( out1 );

        out1.flush();
        out1.close();

        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseComplete())
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e){...}
 }
```

And it works perfect... BUT (here is the problem) **I need to hide the controls of the PDF to the user of the application**...

Is it possible to hide the toolbar with any parameter or something similar?
Is it possible to take the control of the pdf reader plugin?
Is it possible to include any kind of script inside the PDF to hide the toolbar?

***Thanks A LOT***.

Comment: *"How can I hide .."*  More importantly, what is the **point** of doing so?

Comment: Show the same view to all the users indenpendently the configuration, more screen avaiable...

Comment: So, What is the **point** of the document of Adobe then... ? ;)

Comment: I'd suggest 'presenting documents' as opposed to 'being the slave to some programmer'.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use #toolbar=0 with the url 
ex: `http://somesite.com/file.pdf#toolbar=0`

this would open the pdf document in the browser without a toolbar.

[here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) is a document from adobe on available options while  displaying pdf's

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the response. I don´t have any URL, I have my application oppened and a response, no more.

Comment: if you are displaying the pdf in a webbrowser, then the options i've mentioned will take effect.. if the pdf is opened outside the webbrowser (in say pdf reader app) then the toolbar cannot be hidden.

Comment: I am displaying the pdf as an "attachment" but **I don´t have any URL because I throw the document to the response**.

Comment: In that case. you cannot hide the toolbar.. since the toolbar is not in your control.. also why would you try &  hide the toolbar outside the browser?

Comment: Yes, that´s the point... Because this I´m trying to find any "happy idea" for doing that. I can hide the toolbar but I´m interested in showing the same screen for all the users independently the configuration. If they show the toolbar after the PDF is shown, then that´s not my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the document of Adobe, but I am with the same... I have not a URL, I have a Java response